# Can my app receive notification, when it is closed by system?

Tags: android

When my android app goes to background, it may be closed by system to reclaim resources. Can I detect this moment and run some code? Is there any notification (method called) when it happens?

Comment: BTW: weak accept ratio, mate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer is "NO". When Android wants to shut down your application to reclaim resources it just **kills your process**. That's it. No warning, no callback, no chance to do anything at all.

Answer (score 1):

Try catching SIGKILL from a native (NDK/JNI) library. But you won't be able to do almost anything of value in the signal processing code; definitely not call back into the Java world. Signal handlers are heavily limited by *nix rules.

What is it that you're trying to accomplish in the first place? All sensible cleanup is normally performed in activity termination code (`onDestroy()`). Process lifetime shouldn't be your concern under most usage scenarios, as it's explicitly documented as unpredictable.

Comment: I try to save object state to recover it when activity is started next time. At present, I save it in onSaveInstanceState via serialization to a file. What I dislike about it is the fact that the object is serialized each time my activity moves out from top of stack (except the case when back button has been pressed). So I do a lot of unnecessary work. I would like to save the object ONLY when process is killed.

Comment: Don't save into a file, save into a bundle, like Android suggests. The rules for persisting said bundle (or keeping it in the memory) are up to the system. Second-guessing the system is a risky business in general.

Answer (score 0):

Implement `onDestroy()` method of `Activity`.

See [Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/images/activity_lifecycle.png)

Comment: I believe the OP wants to catch the process shutdown, not the activity shutdown. Pressing Back closes the activity, but leaves the app running, provided the memory is not running low.

Comment: If the process is killed by Android, onDestroy() is **not** called on any activities in the process. They just go away. With no warning. Poof! Gone.